# Retrofit: D/Response: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java, retrofit2, rx-java2

I want to get the first "City" object from this JSON response from a URL (or get them all as an array and then use .map() operator in RxJava to get the first city):

```
{
    totalResultsCount: 5,
    names: [
        {
            city: stockholm
        },
        {
            city: oslo
        },
        {
            city: london
        },
        {
            city: moscow
        },
        {
            city: mumbai
        }
    ]
}
```

Here is code responsible for getting this:

```
public interface MyApi {

    @GET("searchJSON?")
    Observable<City[]> getPopulation(
        @QueryMap Map<String, String> queries
    );

}
```

and this class

```
public class MyApiService{

    private final String baseUrl = "myapiurl";
    private MyApi api;
    private final Gson gson;
    private final OkHttpClient okHttpClient;

    public MyApiService(){
        gson = new Gson();
        HttpLoggingInterceptor httpLoggingInterceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        httpLoggingInterceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BASIC);
        okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();
        okHttpClient.newBuilder().addInterceptor(httpLoggingInterceptor);
        buildApi();
    }

    private void buildApi(){
        api = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(baseUrl)
                .client(okHttpClient)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                .build()
                .create(MyApi.class);
    }

    public Observable<City> getPopulation(String city) {
        return api
                .getPopulation(city)
                .map(c -> c[0])
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());
    }
}
```

When I call getPopulation from an activity, I get this message:

> D/Response: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column
>   2 path $

Here is how my City class looks like:

```
public class City {

    @SerializedName("city")
    private String name;

    public City(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

**EDIT:**

I tried adding a custom deserializer like:

```
public class MyDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<City> {

    @Override
    public City deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
        JsonElement cities = json.getAsJsonObject().get("names");
        return new Gson().fromJson(cities, City.class);
    }

}
```

and changing to:

```
gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .registerTypeAdapter(City.class, new MyDeserializer())
                .create();
```

but I still get the exact same response as earlier.

Comment: Delete my answer because it is Rx question I thougth the problem was JSON, try to add the relevant information using the wrapper class mentioned

Comment: @cutiko your answer was kinda helpful too. I managed to solve this by changing GET method and my getcities method and add some relevant RxJava methods. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Welcomr, post the solution then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manage to solve this.

I changed my API calls to:

```
@GET("searchJSON?")
    Observable<ResponseBody> getPopulation(
        @QueryMap Map<String, String> queries
    );
```

And I changed my api call method to:

```
public Observable<City> getPopulation(String city) {
        return api
                .getPopulation(city)
                .map(c -> c.getCities().get(0))
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());
```

And I changed my Serializeble POJOs to:

```
public class ResponseBody implements Serializable
{

    @SerializedName("totalResultsCount")
    @Expose
    private int totalResultsCount;
    @SerializedName("names")
    @Expose
    private List<City> cities = null;

    public ResponseBody() {
    }

    public ResponseBody(int totalResultsCount, List<City> cities) {
        super();
        this.totalResultsCount = totalResultsCount;
        this.cities = cities;
    }

    public int getTotalResultsCount() {
        return totalResultsCount;
    }

    public void setTotalResultsCount(int totalResultsCount) {
        this.totalResultsCount = totalResultsCount;
    }

    public List<City> getCities() {
        return cities;
    }

    public void setNames(List<City> cities) {
        this.cities = cities;
    }

}
```

and

```
public class City implements Serializable
{
    @SerializedName("name")
    @Expose
    private String name;

    public City() {
    }

    public City(String name) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

And I complete removed the custom Deserializer.

It was a combination of my POJO and Wrong choice of RxJava operations which led to my problem. I hope this answer might help someone in the future.

If anyone have a better solution/way to handle this I would appreciate comments.

Answer (score 0):

Your custom deserializer uses `getAsJsonObject("names")` but names is a JsonArray in your json response.

```
names: [] // This is a JsonArray

names: {} // This is a JsonObject
```

Comment: Any suggestions how i could parse to return city array from my get method?